# How to choose Chrome in Windows Kiosk mode instead of Edge

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, kiosk

See screenshot, how to make Chrome appear as one of the apps? Chrome is not listed as one of the 'official' apps in the application list. [image].

Windows 10 Enterprise - 10.0.17763

Answer (score 2):

> How to make Chrome appear as one of the apps?

What you want is not possible.  The built-in Windows 10 kiosk feature only supports `Universal Windows Platform (UWP)` applications.

Since Chrome is not a `Universal Windows Platform` application it cannot be assigned, which means Chrome is incompatible, with the built-in kiosk feature.  **This means if you want to have Chrome within a Kiosk environment you must use a third-party application to implement your kiosk.**